# Divorce legal proceedings, 3rd party information

Tags: divorce, georgia

My wife has been approached by a friend who is going through a tough divorce, and has now fallen into an unofficial therapist role for this person.  The things they have discussed, while not criminal, would certainly lead to a divorce (or two) and would absolutely make my wife's friend's divorce much messier should it become generally known (as in, if my wife's friend's husband found out).

Is my wife putting herself at risk (legally) should it come out that her friend has confided information that is relevant to one (or more) divorce proceeding(s)?  Could she (and by extension, me) end up getting tangled up in depositions and whatever if any of these proceedings end up going to open court?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you and your wife knows come from what you have been told by this friend, that would be hearsay and inadmissible evidence. There would be no valid reason to depose either one of you against your will.